# Cannot add new obstacle to fluid scene

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am experimenting with fluid physics simulation. I would like to create a pool of liquid that has been "baked" and that I can reuse for different experiments. However it seems that if I add an obstacle mesh later in the scene, after the liquid has been baked, it does not interact with the liquid. I find this strange because it is possible to create a scene in which the obstacle and the liquid are not on contact at the time of baking.... so why can't I then add another object after the baking?
Here is my model:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5...ew?usp=sharing

Comment: because baking the sim makes all calculations final. to edit the sim (like adding a new object) you will have to re bake it.